# Getting Parent node from Json object with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get parent node in json object by child it
The json i am getting from client is a multilevel directory hierarchy
the hierarchy is like

```
Root
   -
   -Folder-1
           -folder1(a)
           -folder1(b)
   -folder-2
   -folder-3
           -folder3(a)
```

what i want is, 
when I put `folder3(a)`'s id it should give me `folder-3`'s id and name

**Here is the fiddle with actual json object** http://jsfiddle.net/jftrg9ko/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to search through the tree anyway so just remember the parent and return that if you found the right child.

I fiddled something: http://jsfiddle.net/jftrg9ko/1/

```
function getParent(tree, childNode)
{
    var i, res;
    if (!tree || !tree.folder) {
        return null;
    }
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call(tree.folder) === '[object Array]' ) {
        for (i in tree.folder) {
            if (tree.folder[i].id === childNode) {
                return tree;
            }
            res = getParent(tree.folder[i], childNode);
            if (res) {
                return res;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        if (tree.folder.id === childNode) {
            return tree;
        }
        return getParent(tree.folder, childNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all ocuurences

```
var pars,k,v,chk;
    pars = [];
    $.each(json,function(k,v){
        chk = k;
        $.each(v,function(k,v)
            if(k === node){
                pars.push(chk);
            }
        })
    })
```