# How to find parentNode from childNode in a JSON structure using jsonPath or an alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to find out a parentNode from childNode in a JSON structure. For example I need to know what is the parent for  `"view_id": "f"`.

I am evaluating [jsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) but I cannot find a parent operator.

I would like to now:

- does jsonPath has a parent operator or has an alternative operator that can be used similarly instead?
- if not any alternative library or solution?

You can test JSON structure here: http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

```
[
    {
        "view_id": "a",
        "views": [
            {
                "view_id": "b",
                "views": [
                    {
                        "view_id": "c"
                    },
                    {
                        "view_id": "d"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "view_id": "e",
                "views": [
                    {
                        "view_id": "f"
                    },
                    {
                        "view_id": "g"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "view_id": "h"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "view_id": "i",
        "views": [
            {
                "view_id": "l",
                "views": [
                    {
                        "view_id": "m",
                        "views": [
                            {
                                "view_id": "n"
                            },
                            {
                                "view_id": "o"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "view_id": "p"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "view_id": "q"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little about why you need this? Surely if you know the location of the child element, you must know the location of its parent to traverse to it...?

Comment: See if this is better: http://jsonselect.org/#tryit

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25542368/1138214

Comment: I need to navigate the tree, using sibling and parent nodes. Maybe I am thinking the wrong approach. any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found two possible solutions to this specif problem as for my understanding `jsonPath` does not allow me to find the `parent` for a node:

Solution A:

- Adding a property "parent_id" to every node in the JSON, query the JSON using jsonPath.

Solution B:

- Not using jsonPath for this task and instead keeping an in memory rap-presentation of the JSON as a "flat" array, when populating the array I can add to each node a "parent_id" as to find a child node I always need to know its parent (as suggested from comments). Any search is done on the "flat" array using JS.

Comment: can i use some XPath library for that kind of task. XPath supports moving to parentnode. Can you suggest some library for that?