# how to counts parent in an javascript object (getting not defined error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a object which could the number of parents of element .
I have a array of objects .in which there is two field **to** and **from** .I want to calculate the length of parents 
here is my code ?

Example

- **"node_from": 11,** don't have parent ..it don't have **to** field .so it length is **0**,zero;
- **"node_from": 12,** is coming from 11 .so it have parent .so it parent length is one or 1 and same as in 13 , 14,16,18,19.
- **"node_from": 15,** has 2 parent coming from 13 and 14 ..so it length is 2 .

can we find this

here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/ood2ezvz/2/

```
var obj={}
for(var i=0;i<node.length;i++){

console.log(node[i]);
var node=node[i]
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(node.node_from)){
obj[node_from]=obj[node_from]++;
}else{
obj[node_from]=0;
}

}
console.log(obj)
```

It is giving error ?

**Expected out put** `{ 11:0, 12:1, 13:1, 14:1, 15:2, 16:1, 17:1, 18:1 19:1 }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Parent node from Json object with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542024/getting-parent-node-from-json-object-with-jquery)

Comment: no it is different from my question

Comment: So you are trying to make a linked-list in which any node can count how many parents it has?

Comment: yes please check fiddle for expacted output

Comment: It seems like each node should have an ID or something, and if you are trying to use the arrays index as an ID then none of them have any parents because the array is only 9 items long. So what in the world is going on here?

Comment: there is two id's ..`node_to` and `node_from`

Comment: please check the output also http://plnkr.co/edit/4reBdiFZyFM1CiVzMra1?p=preview

Comment: node1 don't have parent it's length is 0, node second have one parent which is node one so it length is 1..same as in third and fourth ..but first have two parent third and fourth ..so it length is 2

Comment: First off no an id is unique, so maybe "node_from" is the id, but "node_to" most certainly is not an ID. secondly "node_from" is an odd name for id that's kind of confusing. "id" would have worked better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "node_from" is the ID of the current node, and "node_to" is the children each node points to. Here is a function which can count the children of each node.

```js
var node=[
  {
   
    "node_from": 11,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   
    "node_from": 12,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 13
      },
      {
        "node_to": 14
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "node_from": 13,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 15
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "node_from": 14,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 15
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   
    "node_from": 15,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 16
      },
      {
        "node_to": 17
      },
      {
        "node_to": 18
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "node_from": 16,
    "children": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "node_from": 17,
    "children": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "node_from": 18,
    "children": [
      {
        "node_to": 19
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    
    "node_from": 19,
    "children": [
      
    ]
  }
];

function countParents(nodes, num){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
   if(nodes[i].children){
     for(var e=0;e<nodes[i].children.length;e++){
        if(nodes[i].children[e].node_to == num)
          count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}

function countEachParents(nodes){
  var output = [];
  for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    output.push( nodes[i].node_from + ":" + countParents(nodes, nodes[i].node_from) );
  }
  return output;
}

document.getElementById( "output" ).innerHTML = countEachParents(node).join(", ");
```

```html
{<span id='output'></span>}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zwttLty7/

Personally I would use OOP with methods to handle something like this...

```js
function Node(id, children){
  this.id = id;
  this.children = children || [];
  this.countParents = function(nodeList){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<nodeList.length;i++){
      if(nodeList.children.indexOf(this.id) > -1)
        count++;
    }
    return count;
  };
};
function NodeList(nodes){
  this.list = nodes || [];
  this.parentCounts = function(){
    var output = [];
    for(var i=0;i<this.list.length;i++){
      var count = 0;
      for(var e=0;e<this.list.length;e++){
        if(this.list[e].children.indexOf(this.list[i].id) > -1)
          count++;
      }
      output.push(this.list[i].id+":"+count);
    }
    return output.join(", ");
  }
};

var nodes = new NodeList([
  new Node(11, [12]),
  new Node(12, [13,14]),
  new Node(13, [15]),
  new Node(14, [15]),
  new Node(15, [16,17,18]),
  new Node(16),
  new Node(17),
  new Node(18, [19]),
  new Node(19)
]);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = nodes.parentCounts();
```

```html
{<span id='output'></span>}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otcm76oy/

Comment: please share fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code with this jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ood2ezvz/8/

Essentially you were using `hasOwnProperty` incorrectly in this context.  What appears to work well is `undefined`.  The code below gets the exact output that you are looking for.  Count how many `node_to` are in the children and set the original `node_from` to 0.

```
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    var new_node = node[i];
  console.log(new_node);
  if (typeof obj[new_node.node_from] === 'undefined') {
    obj[new_node.node_from] = 0;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < new_node.children.length; j++) {
    if (typeof obj[new_node.children[j].node_to] !== 'undefined') {
        obj[new_node.children[j].node_to]++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

This proposal uses an temporary object for the parents and returns then the length of every parent.

```js
function getParentCount(nodes) {
    var parent = {}, o = {};
    nodes.forEach(function (n) {
        parent[n.node_from] = parent[n.node_from] || [];
        n.children.forEach(function (a) {
            parent[a.node_to] = parent[a.node_to] || [];
            parent[a.node_to].push(n.node_from);
        });
    });
    Object.keys(parent).forEach(function (k) { o[k] = parent[k].length; });
    return o;
}

var nodes = [{ "node_from": 11, "children": [{ "node_to": 12 }] }, { "node_from": 12, "children": [{ "node_to": 13 }, { "node_to": 14 }] }, { "node_from": 13, "children": [{ "node_to": 15 }] }, { "node_from": 14, "children": [{ "node_to": 15 }] }, { "node_from": 15, "children": [{ "node_to": 16 }, { "node_to": 17 }, { "node_to": 18 }] }, { "node_from": 16, "children": [] }, { "node_from": 17, "children": [] }, { "node_from": 18, "children": [{ "node_to": 19 }] }, { "node_from": 19, "children": [] }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getParentCount(nodes), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a recursive function like so:-

```js
var node = [{

  "node_from": 11,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 12
  }]
}, {

  "node_from": 12,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 13
  }, {
    "node_to": 14
  }]
}, {
  "node_from": 13,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 15
  }]
}, {

  "node_from": 14,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 15
  }]
}, {

  "node_from": 15,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 16
  }, {
    "node_to": 17
  }, {
    "node_to": 18
  }]
}, {

  "node_from": 16,
  "children": [

  ]
}, {
  "node_from": 17,
  "children": [

  ]
}, {

  "node_from": 18,
  "children": [{
    "node_to": 19
  }]
}, {

  "node_from": 19,
  "children": [

  ]
}]

function recursiveSearch(node_from, count) {
  for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    var current = node[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < current.children.length; j++) {
      var child = current.children[j];
      if (node_from == child.node_to)
        recursiveSearch(current.node_from, ++count);
    }
  }
  return count;
}

var obj = {}
for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
  var current = node[i]
  if (current.hasOwnProperty('node_from')) {
    obj[current.node_from] = recursiveSearch(current.node_from, 0);
  }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '</pre>')
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
var obj={}
node.forEach(function(object){
    if(!obj[object.node_from])
      obj[object.node_from] = 0;
    object.children.forEach(function(child){
        if(!obj[child.node_to])
          obj[child.node_to] = 0;
        obj[child.node_to]++;
    })
})
console.log(obj);
```